# Scala Json validation does not result in JsError on Option field

Tags: json, scala, validation, field, scala-option

I am using PlayFramework 2.6. I have the following classes

```
case class Account(homePage: URL, name: String)
object Account {
    import implicits.ReadsWrites.urlFormat
    implicit val format: Format[Account] = Json.format[Account]
}
```

And `account` is an optional field of type `Account`

```
case class IdentifiedGroup(objectType: String,
                       name: Option[String],
                       member: Option[Seq[Agent]],
                       mbox: Option[URI],
                       mboxSHA1SUM: Option[String],
                       openID: Option[URI],
                       account: Option[Account]) extends Group
```

When `name` field in `Account` is not a string but an object such as `"name": { "key": "this should fail" }` 
Then when I apply reads on IdentifiedGroup, the `account` will be None.

But the expected behaviour is that if `account` is present and invalid then I want JsError as a result instead.

I've been googling for more than a day and still can't seem to find the right answer :(

Thanks

Comment: This feels a bit surprising... but I guess it makes sense. I think you're going to have to write the explicit Format. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Validation-with-Reads

Comment: This really should work out of the box. How did you implement `Reads[IdentifiedGroup]`?

Comment: `object test {
  case class Account(name: String)
  case class IdentifiedGroup(objectType: String,
                             name: Option[String],
                             acc: Option[Account])

  implicit val formatAcc: Format[Account] = Json.format[Account]
  implicit val format: Format[IdentifiedGroup] = Json.format[IdentifiedGroup]

  def main( args:Array[String] ):Unit = {
    println(format.reads(Json.parse("""{"objectType": "type1", "name": "name1", "acc": { "name": {"type": "bla"}}}""")))
  }` 
For me this code fails, Maybe you can provide more information?